# Can I use Docker-Compose to create Networks without Containers

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I've been playing with Docker-Compose for the last few days to see if it would simplify my Docker Container and Network building process.

I'm pretty happy with it, but ran into a problem when I wanted to create a few 'Networks' that didn't get used by any 'Services' (yet).

The reason I want this behavior was to have a Docker-Compose file to create my local fabric of 'Private' network and 'Public' Network. And a separate Docker-Compose for each of my projects that utilize those already created 'external' networks.

I noted that I was able to just specify a dummy container to initialize the creation of the Networks, but it seemed unnecessary. e.g..

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Dummy Service
  dummy:
    image: busybox
    container_name: dummy
    hostname: dummy
    networks:
      private:

networks:
  # Private Network for all Services (across Projects)
  private:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.18.0.1
```

Is there a setting/flag that I'm overlooking, or is there currently no way to use Docker-Compose to create Networks without Containers.

Additionally, am I just approaching this incorrectly?

**Essentially I'd like to have a network that live on regardless of what containers join/leave it.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a check inside of docker-compose for whether the network is used, and if it's unused, it skips creating the network:

```
$ cat docker-compose.net-only.yml
version: '2'

networks:
  test1:
  test2:

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.net-only.yml --verbose up
.....
WARNING: compose.network.from_services: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: test1, test2
.....

$ docker network ls | grep test

$
```

I'd recommend doing this as a small shell script, calling `docker network create` instead of trying to use docker-compose for this task.

Comment: Thanks BMitch. This was my suspicion, just wanted to check I wasn't missing a flag to 'ignore services' or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

docker-compose-networks.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    works:
        image: scratch
        restart: always
        container_name: net_works
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - "node.hostname==scratch"
        networks:
            - mynet1
            - mynet2

networks:
    mynet1:
        name: mynet1
        driver: overlay
        attachable: false
    mynet2:
        name: mynet2
        driver: overlay
        attachable: true
```

Comment: Nice workaround, but does not work with version 3.5 (which comes with docker-compose version 1.18, which in turns comes with centos 7.8)
Furthermore, lots of lines.... but +1 for the good idea.

Comment: Thx.
If you can, you may update docker-compose:
```
wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 -O /opt/bin/docker-compose && \
chmod 755 /opt/bin/docker-compose && \
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose -O /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

All my docker images and networks etc.. files I like to run with docker-compose. So while my thought process is on docker-compose I just have docker-compose network files that spin up a hello-world image (many people already have the image, else it is like 2kb) and then it immediately exits the image of coarse but keeps the network.

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    hello_world:
        image: hello-world:latest
        networks: 
            main_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.255
networks: 
    main_net:
        name: main_network
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

This way I plan my network and lay it out nicely in docker-compose file with th minimum overhead...

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but worked for me.

```yaml
version: "2.1"
                                                                                                                                
services:                                                                                                                                     
  network-only:                                                                                                                               
    image: tianon/true                                                                                                                        
    container_name: network-only                                                                                                              
    networks:
      - mybr0

networks:
  mybr0:
    name: mybr0
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: mybr0
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to set an "ipv4_address" which is in your bridge subnet range, just like @Alfa Bravo said.

Such as

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Dummy Service
  dummy:
    image: busybox
    container_name: dummy
    hostname: dummy
    networks:
      private:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2


networks:
  # Private Network for all Services (across Projects)
  private:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.18.0.1
```

So `docker-compose` can add your own bridge successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to create a network for docker compose using docker network create. I had similar issue where I needed to know before hand the network IPAM, but didn't want to hardcode it. This is what I used to create the network before running `docker compose up`:

`docker network create -d bridge --attachable --label "com.docker.compose.network=default" --label "com.docker.compose.project=<name-of-the-compose-project>" <name-of-the-network>`

Being the compose file something like:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  main:
    image: busybox
    extra_hosts:
      - mylocaldns:${DOCKER_IPAM}

networks:
  default:
    name: <name-of-the-network>
```

With all this, I could run the below commands allowing the compose file to grab the newly created network IP gateway.

`DOCKER_IPAM=$(docker network inspect -f '{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' <name-of-the-network>) docker compose -p <name-of-the-compose-project> up`

Hope it helps someone!